# Export `gt` table to LaTeX with colors

Tags: r, latex, gt

I cannot see how to add the color of the cells when I export a `gt` table to LaTeX.

```
gt::exibble |>
  dplyr::select(num) |>
  gt::gt() |>
  gt::tab_style(
    style = gt::cell_fill(color = "lightcyan"),
    locations = gt::cells_body(
      columns = num,
      rows = num >= 5000
    )
  ) |>
  gt::as_latex() |>
  as.character()
```

The previous table should have some light blue cells, which are perfectly visible using the HTML rendering.

However, there is no color on the output LaTeX code:

```
\\begin{longtable}{r}\n\\toprule\nnum \\\\ \n\\midrule\n1.111e-01 \\\\ \n2.222e+00 \\\\ \n3.333e+01 \\\\ \n4.444e+02 \\\\ \n5.550e+03 \\\\ \nNA \\\\ \n7.770e+05 \\\\ \n8.880e+06 \\\\ \n\\bottomrule\n\\end{longtable}\n
```

Does this mean that `gt` still do not support colors in this situation, or my implementation is wrong?

Comment: This is an outstanding (in the not-yet-resolved way) issue: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/351.

Comment: @r2evans ... dating back from 2019.  Little hope to have it implemented, I guess.

Comment: While it seemed to have gone dormant for a couple of years, the dev on `gt` has picked up recently. It's issue-list is not too long, but I'm guessing the devs either have forgotten about it (focusing a lot on html/shiny out, perhaps?) or don't have it high on their priority list. There is also [discussion 1300](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/discussions/1300), though unfilled atm. I suggest that "squeaky wheels" might either help remind/motivate dev, or at least solicit a clearer reason why it has not been implemented (though latex _can_ do color in tables).

Comment: (At least to click on the "up arrow" on that discussion, a preferred method of "me too" vice a literal comment saying that. I just did, since I've wanted this feature for a while as well.)